# Run thread groups concurrently but evenly distributed over time

Tags: time, concurrency, jmeter, distribution

I have a `Test plan` with several `Thread Groups (TG)` which have a different `Loop Count`.

```
Test Plan
|--TG 1: loop count=5
|--TG 2: loop count=10
|--TG 3: loop count=3
```

These thread groups are executed concurrently. However because the loop count of threads differ, some threads are finished while others are still running. What I would like is for `JMeter` to manage the execution of each `Thread Group` based on a ratio of the the highest `Loop Count` in the `Test plan` in order to create a more even time distribution and ensure all `Thread Groups` roughly end at the same time. For instance:

```
Test Plan
|--TG 1: loop count=5, execute every 2 occurrences of TG 2
|--TG 2: loop count=10
|--TG 3: loop count=3, execute every 3.3 occurrences of TG 2
```

In terms of execution, things would look like this:

```
[round 1] TG1: run  | TG2: run  | TG3: run
[round 2] TG1: wait | TG2: run  | TG3: wait
[round 3] TG1: run  | TG2: run  | TG3: wait
[round 4] TG1: wait | TG2: run  | TG3: run
etc...
```

**Can I configure JMeter to acheive this, if so how?**